# I can not reconnect to Internet after using VPN

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, ubuntu-16.04

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and when I connect to VPN services like Fruho/Windscribe, after I disconnect the Wi-Fi, I see this icon replaced with the Wi-Fi icon:
[image]

And when I connect to Wi-Fi again, it doesn't open the websites and I must restart either my computer or connect to the vpn service again!

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Ping 8.8.4.4 - if this works, it will be a DNS issue

Comment: @davidbaumann: No command 'Ping'